# HubSpot API - How to get the logo of a Company?

Tags: hubspot, hubspot-api

I am working on a project in which I am integrating HubSpot API.
I want to collect the company information. Everything is working fine but I didn't get the company logo.

As I checked, there are possible cases for the company logo:

1. If company name is not found on social media or in HubSpot storage, then a place holder image is showing like this:

[image]

2. If company name is found on social media or in HubSpot storage, then it will show logo:

[image]

3. Third possibility is that, user can add custom logo for a company at HubSpot.

I checked HubSpot API, it have a key `hs_avatar_filemanager_key`, but it is returning only logo which are uploaded by user from the HubSpot portal (#3).

Is there any way to get the logo, which I mentioned in #1 and #2 (same as showing on HubSpot portal).

Thanks,